# Eloquent JavaScript 3rd Edition Chapter 5 Exercise 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions

I'm having difficulty with this particular exercise from the newest, 3rd Edition.  This is the Higher-Order Functions chapter.  Chapter 5 in this edition.  The exercise prompt is below:

"Analogous to the *some* method, arrays also have an *every* method.  This one returns true when the given function returns true for *every* element in the array.  In a way, *some* is a version of the || operators that acts on arrays, and *every* is like the && operator.

Implement *every* as a function that takes an array and a predicate function as parameters.  Write two versions, one using a loop and one using the *some* method."

On the code [sandbox](https://eloquentjavascript.net/code/#5.3) the suggested function looks like below:

```
function every(array, test) {
// Your code here.
}
```

The test samples look like below:

```
console.log(every([1, 3, 5], n => n < 10));
// → true
console.log(every([2, 4, 16], n => n < 10));
// → false
console.log(every([], n => n < 10));
// → true
```

Looking at the test cases, I can't seem to quite figure out how I get the array parameter to pass into the test parameter, where the test parameter can be ANYTHING.  The author just says "a predicate function."  I guess I could stick with using *n* as the variable but it seems that the author wants me to write my own array.prototype.every() method.

Does anyone have any insights on what this exercise is getting at?  Or maybe someone would like to point out what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call a function, you don't care what the name of the parameter variables are. You simply pass the value you want as an argument, and the function handles the rest.

So you simply call the `test()` function with the current element of the array as the argument.

```js
function every(array, test) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (!test(array[i])) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(every([1, 3, 5], n => n < 10));
// → true
console.log(every([2, 4, 16], n => n < 10));
// → false
console.log(every([], n => n < 10));
// → true
```

Comment: Ah man... I wish you hadn't given me the answer... but I see now.  Man I feel like I've got a lot to learn.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer the question without showing the code as an example. You obviously didn't understand the general explanation in your textbook, and I doubt I could have explained it better.

Comment: Ok, so, reading onto the second portion of the exercise, I'm to use the .some() method to garner the same boolean values as the loop.  This seems a bit difficult because .some() returns true if at least one element in the array is true.  Well, looking at each test, each array has something that will return true.

Any insight into what I'm missing?

Comment: Google "de Morgan's Laws"

Comment: 1. Thanks for responding and the article.  I appreciate your help.

2. I looked at the explanation and I see something of an issue.  [].some(el => test(el)) returns false, because an empty array used with .some() returns as false, according to MDN.  However, negating the test with an empty array, returns false as well: [].some(el=> !test(el)).  Shouldn't it return true?

3. I've got more to learn.

Comment: No. With an empty array, it doesn't matter what the test is -- some() is always false, every() is always true.

Comment: It's because these are the identity values for `||` and `&&`. The rule is that `x.some(test) || y.some(test) == (x.concat(y)).some(test)`.